# Run Emacs command from terminal and terminate

Tags: bash

Is there a way to open a file on emacs, execute a command and quit, quietly?
I tried

```
emacs file --eval '(progn (cmd) (kill-emacs))'
```

But if I execute this, emacs shows up briefly before quitting. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the batch mode to run some commands on a file. It's described in [`(emacs) Initial Options`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html).

Comment: Is there a way to make emacs load the int file in batch mode?

Comment: You can just use the `load` function to do that, but keep in mind that it will make your scripts depend on your configuration, which might not be what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run emacs as an elisp interpreter, consider using the `--script` command line switch, like,

```
emacs --script my-script.el
```

One can use emacs as `shebang`,

```
#!emacs --script
```

See [related page on EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsScripts).

Also, [Run Emacs Lisp Code in Shell](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_running_script_in_batch_mode.html).